# How to make ImageView from gallery bigger when clicked

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I have a gallery in my app, with a `GridLayout` and I want that when the user clicks on it, it pops **[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sy76.jpg)** effect , ¿How can I achieve that? 
if anyone could tell me how the effect it is called or a library or something to how can I do that I would really appreciate it, so far I have tried this library with no luck  https://github.com/mzelzoghbi/ZGallery?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=4987

Here is my code if anyone could see the error:

```
public class BusinessPremiumGallery extends AppCompatActivity implements GridClickListener
{
GalleryAdapter galleryAdapter;
    Gson gson;
    private static final Type BUSINESS_TYPE = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Business>>() {}.getType();

    JsonObject images;
    GridLayoutManager layoutManager;
    ArrayList<Business> arrayGallery;
    ArrayList<String> arrayImages;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_business_premium_gallery);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        final int values = bundle.getInt("no");
        new PlifRequestBase(BusinessPremiumGallery.this) {

            @Override
            public JsonObject onHttpOk(JsonObject response) throws JSONException {
                JsonObject respuesta, details, location, geolocation, matrix, schedules_array;
                JsonArray data,branches, phones, schedules,extra_services,user_images;
                respuesta = response;
                int catalog_id;
                String catalog_descrip,catalog_name,catalog_image,image;

                Log.d("VALUES2",String.valueOf(values));
                arrayGallery=new ArrayList<Business>();
                gson=new Gson();
                user_images= respuesta.get("user_images").getAsJsonArray();


                if(user_images.size()<0){
                    arrayGallery=null;
                    images=null;

                }else {
                    arrayGallery=gson.fromJson(user_images,BUSINESS_TYPE);
                    for (int i = 0; i < user_images.size(); i++) {
                        images = user_images.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                        image=images.get("image").getAsString();
                       Log.d("IMAGES",image);
                        Log.d("CATALOG",String.valueOf(images));

                    }


                }
                if (BusinessPremiumGallery.this == null)
                    return response;
                BusinessPremiumGallery.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView) BusinessPremiumGallery.this.findViewById(R.id.recycler_gallery);
                        galleryAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(BusinessPremiumGallery.this, arrayGallery, R.layout.row_gallery_premium);
                        recycler.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(BusinessPremiumGallery.this, 2);
                        recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                        recycler.setAdapter(galleryAdapter);
                    }

                });

                return respuesta;
            }

            @Override
            public void onHttpCreate(JsonObject response) throws JSONException
            {

            }
        }.execute("businesses/"+String.valueOf(values), "GET");
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {

        super.onBackPressed();  // optional depending on your needs
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(int i) {
        ZGallery.with(this, arrayImages)


                .show();
    }
}
```

Comment: zGallery was not implemented to do this kind of animations, however, you can try this library https://github.com/RiccardoMoro/LongPressPopup